# Python read .txt-files header

Tags: python, file, numpy

I need to read some information from a txt file header which looks like this:

```
Date    20160122
SP Number   8
Gauge   250N internal
Total Height    61
SP Modell   SP2
Corner Distance 150 

Height  Value   Comment
60  NaN 
...
```

I have a python program program currently doing this:

```
depth, N = npy.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=8, unpack=True, usecols = usecols)
```

However I would like to read out some of the values from the header. Is there a way to do this? I am mostly interested to get the value of "Total Height". On my search I only seem to find answers concerning .csv files.

Comment: The entries in the header are separated by a `\t` delimiter. So I can use this as a safe way to split the strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `open` rather than `npy.loadtxt`

```
with open(filename, 'r') as the_file:
    all_data = [line.strip() for line in the_file.readlines()]
    height_line = all_data[3]
    data = all_data[8:]
```

Then you can parse the value of `height_line`, to get the Total Height. And all your data from the file will be in the variable `data`.

Comment: how do I parse it and how do I get the values `N` and `depth` out of `data`?

Comment: I added `height = height_line.split('\t')[1]` and that solves my problem nicely. I also added some filters with `height_line.find('\t')`,`math.isnan` and `panda.isnull()` and it also catches nans and empty entries.

Answer (score 1):

This should work!

```
field = "Total Height"

# Get first 6 lines
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = [next(file) for x in range(6)]

value = None
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(field):
        # Get the part of the string after the field name
        end_of_string = line[len(field):]

        # Convert it to an int:
        value = int(end_of_string.strip())

print(value) #Should print 61
```

If you know that the field names and values are separated by a tab character instead of spaces, you could instead use `line.split('\t')` to break each line into the field name and field value, and then just check if field_name is the field you care about, and if so, use the value, instead of using `startswith` and then slicing the resulting string to get the end of it.

Comment: It works. I only have the issue, that some of the files have a `NaN` entry or even a empty entry. Is there a way to filter that?

Comment: You could put the value = ... line inside a try/except block, so that if it tries to parse something thats not a number, the except block catches the exception and sets value equal to None.  Then, after the for loop finishes, you can check if value is equal to None. If not, do your normal thing, and if so, either do nothing or add some logic for what should happen if a file doesnt have a good Total Height specified.  Also, if this answer answers your question, do you mind upvoting it and marking it as correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but with one caveat:

```
import numpy as npy

usecols = (0, 1)

header = {}
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    for header_lines, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: break # assume that a blank line means "header stops here"
        key, value = line.split(' ', 1)
        header[key] = value


depth, N = npy.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=header_lines + 2, unpack=True, usecols=usecols)
```

The problem is that the header format has ambiguity about what is key and what is value. Some keys appear to be multiple space-delimited words, and some values are too, and yet (a non-deterministic amount of) whitespace is **also** apparently the only rule for separating key from value.  In most cases it's 3 spaces between key and value, but `Corner Distance` is only followed by 1 space—it's therefore ambiguous (except to the human brain's own sophisticated context parser) where the key ends and value begins.

Maybe the problem is just bad rendering (on this page, or during copy-paste into SO) of what are really supposed to be tabs.  If so,

```
        key, value = line.split('\t', 1)
```

will solve the problem. But if not, the ambiguity in the file format needs to be resolved before a definitive solution can be written.

Comment: With that I get: `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to split a line on a character (e.g. `'\t'`) that does not appear in the line. It was only a guess on my part that `\t` was being used. As I said, there are issues with the file format that you will have to resolve before proceeding: what *is* the rule that separates keys from values? The code in my answer must be adapted according to the answer to that question, which cannot be determined from your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `re` module, if keys in header file are always the same:

```
file = open(filename, 'r')
data = file.read()
Total = re.findall( 'Total Height\s*([0-9]+)\s*\n', data)[0]
```

I had the same task to read the header file and [did it](https://github.com/GrinJ/CTLReader/blob/master/src/CTLReader/CTLReader.py#L33) with `re` module

Comment: But doesn't that limit it to numbers as entries? I also have letter entries there.

Comment: @brium-brium you can replace `([0-9]+)` with `(.+?)` and it will find any characters after space and before newline